# Return all values in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return all the `productnames` from my MySQL table. At the moment this only returns the first name in the column

```
public function selectAll () 
{

    $stmt = Database::get()->query('SELECT * FROM retrofootball_products');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        return $row['productname'];

    }
}
```

How do I get it to loop through and select all the productnames?

Comment: Change `*` to `productname`.

Comment: @RomanNewaza You know * means select all right?

Comment: Is is not alright. He needs only single column and it is bad practice to use `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do is just select only the `productname` column, and then use `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.

```
public function selectAll () 
{
    $stmt = Database::get()->query('SELECT `productname` FROM retrofootball_products');

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: How will I then remove the keys so its just the data?

Comment: If you are using `PHP 5.3` or later, you could use: `array_walk($array_of_data, function (&$a) { $a = $a['productname']; });` where `$array_of_data` is your array returned from `selectAll()`.

Comment: If i wanted to do this with out an array and just loop through the data giving back each productname how would i do this?

Comment: Again, assuming PHP 5.3 or later, `return array_map(function ($a) { return $a['productname']; }, $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` But in all honesty it would probably be better to just loop over using `->fetch` and then return the array.

Comment: This still returns an array. In a ideal world it would come back each title on its own line with out an array being needed. Guess this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
public function selectAll () {

    $stmt = Database::get()->query('SELECT * FROM retrofootball_products');
    $allCols = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $allCols[] = $row['productname'];
    }
    return $allCols;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are directly returning first value that was causing the problem.
Store each record in array and return that array.

```
public function selectAll () 
{

$stmt = Database::get()->query('SELECT * FROM retrofootball_products');
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $arr[] = $row['productname'];

}
return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, how do I know get rid of the array tags and just have the row I want showing?

Answer (score 0):

You can just avoid looping through as you're using PDO and use fetchAll.

```
public function selectAll () 
{

    $stmt = Database::get()->query('SELECT * FROM retrofootball_products');
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score -1):

While I'm new to stmp too, I imagine this might work

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
// do something with $row
}
```